# Read hyperterminal file(ht file) in R

Tags: r, special-characters, ansi, hyperterminal

Is it possible for R to read/import hyperterminal file(.ht) ?
I have tried to use read.csv, read.table, read_tsv and read.delim, but no one works. I think because the file contain some special character(maybe due to the encoding ANSI but I am not having a very deep understanding on encoding) so that R unable to read it.

Is there any way to remove the rows of special character first before reading/importing the file?
Or can convert the file to txt/convert the encoding to general form(for example UTF-8) ?

This is when I open ht file by notepad
[htfile_notepad](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXWIA.png)

This is when I open ht file by excel
[htfile_excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnmQc.png)

Please help. Thanks a lot!